# Intellij Scala/Java add resource folder

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea, resources, project

My project-structure:

```
-Project
--res
---test.jpg
---bla.xml
--src
---Main.scala
```

Now I want to load bla.xml in my Main.scala

```
object Main
{
   val test = getClass.getResource("res/bla.xml")
}
```

Throws an IOException right into my face. Now how can I add the res-folder to the projects-searchpath?

I've already marked it as "resource folder".

If I place bla.xml at the root and load it with "bla.xml" everything is just fine, so I'm wondering how to do this in Intellij.

**edit: Sascha Kolberg had it right:**

Just use `val test = getClass.getResource("/bla.xml")` if you've added res as an resourcefolder.

Comment: "*Throws an IOException right into my face*" Post the stack trace

Comment: did you create that `resource/resources` folder?

Comment: afaik, all contents or resource folders are placed in the class path root. So try `val test = getClass.getResource("/bla.xml")`

Comment: Thanks @SaschaKolberg, this is the right answer.

Comment: @SaschaKolberg: Could you add this as an answer, so I may accept one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My comment as answer:

afaik, all contents or resource folders are placed in the class path root. So just try

```
val test = getClass.getResource("/bla.xml")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try val test = getClass.getResource("[full_path_to_bla.xml]"). If this works, slightly adjust, then you will figure out the correct relative path.

Please update us the correct one when you found it.